# Getting location Updates in Android

Tags: android, location, updates

Hi AM using the code below used here : [How to get current location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17591147/2943858)
Here am using the TextView to display the location coordinates once.
Now How can I keep update the location in TextView once the location keeps changing.

Codes i'm using now: This is my main Activity

```
package com.example.locationtests;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GPSTracker mGPS = new GPSTracker(this);

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texts);
    if(mGPS.canGetLocation ){
    mGPS.getLocation();
    text.setText("Lat"+mGPS.getLatitude()+"Lon"+mGPS.getLongitude());
    }else{
        text.setText("Unabletofind");
        System.out.println("Unable");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}

This is the class im using for Tracking:

package com.example.locationtests;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public final class GPSTracker implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    public boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    /**
     * Function to get the user's current location
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            Log.v("isGPSEnabled", "=" + isGPSEnabled);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            Log.v("isNetworkEnabled", "=" + isNetworkEnabled);

            if (isGPSEnabled == false && isNetworkEnabled == false) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    location=null;
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    location=null;
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
     * app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * 
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will
     * lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

}
This is my AndroidManifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.locationtests"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.locationtests.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the method requestLocationUpdates on locationManger, you specify 'this' as the LocationListener:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(..., ..., ..., this);
```

That's fine since the class implements LocationListener. The callback made when the location changes is the method 'onLocationChanged'. You have this method in your class but it has no code so does nothing:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}
```

Add appropriate code to get the new Latitude and Longitude from the 'location' parameter and update the TextView back in your Activity. There are a number of ways to do that. Two that come to mind:

1) Pass a reference to the TextView in the GPSTracker class constructor so you can access it from the class.
2) Pass a reference to the Activity in the GPSTracker class constructor so you can call a method in your Activity (that accepts the values to show) that can then update the TextView.

EDIT:

You already have the reference I refer to in point 2 above. When you instantiate your instance of GPSTracker in your Activity, you already pass it 'this':

```
GPSTracker mGPS = new GPSTracker(this);
```

In this case 'this' is the instance of your MainActivity class and an Activity class also happens to be a Context. In the constructor of GPSTracker you are storing this context in a variable:

```
public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
```

You can therefore use it to access the TextView. Cast the context you have to an Activity and you can then use the findViewById method on it:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    TextView text = (TextView) ((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.texts);
    text.setText("Lat"+location.getLatitude()+"Lon"+location.getLongitude());
}
```

Comment: Hi Nigel,

Can you elaborate on of the method as what you have suggested exactly as per my code. Am new to Android and developing slowly.You help would be appreciated.

regards Sam

Comment: NigelK, Superrrrrrrrrb is what I can tell you....Its working and its working in a very good way..he location keeps updating itself at a distance of even less then 1 or 2 m....Awesome ty very much....My problem is solved....regards, Sam

Comment: Nigelk....adding to this....Now i have got the updated coordinates of the location in a file....am in the process of tranfering the file to my laptop and use it further...I cannot use internet services any where in the flow..Summary is I have a file stored in internal storage  of my android phone and I have to send it to my windows based laptop through some wireless network technology without using internet services..I cant use USB as well because the feel needs to get updated with coordinates...

Comment: Sam - I imagine Bluetooth is the way to go. Not something I've dealt with so please raise a new question and you'll get plenty of help on it from others. Thx.

Comment: Thx nigel I have already posted question...one more issue i had is i have to add on changed location coordinates in a file which am doing but it is overwriting the previous one...here am forcibly declaring the file creation and file writer modules inside location changed and if i declare outside its giving me some token error...The output i need is see the code am using

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

Sample code:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
Log.d(TAG, "GPS LocationChanged");
double lat = location.getLatitude();
double lng = location.getLongitude();
Log.d(TAG, "Received GPS request for " + String.valueOf(lat) + "," + String.valueOf(lng)       + " , ready to rumble!");

// Do clever stuff here
}
```

Comment: Am new to this..see I have added this to my code but did not understand what to do next...can you just elaborate...whats the clever stuff that I have to do...can u see my code and give me steps exactly what I have to do..