# google map v2 in android how to get current position automaticaley and main countryes notification

Tags: android, dictionary

google map v2 in android how to get current position and zoom in automatically and main countries selection point notification

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     try {

            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
     @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void initilizeMap() {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(

                        R.id.map)).getMap();
```

googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5.0f));

```
                LocationManager mlocManager =
```

(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

```
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                .title("Your Location is"));



                        if (googleMap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        } 
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            initilizeMap();
        }
```

Comment: You can't expect that other users will solve your complete problem.
There are a lot of similar questions like: "How to get current location" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android) or "How to get current location programmatically" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android).

Comment: no i have solved my problem there is left only bit of problem that is current location how to get only

Comment: You just need the current position? Nothing more?

Comment: yes i want only my current position

Comment: Read the official doc: https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analysing your question you could try this:

```
private LatLng getCurrentPosition(){
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();             // set criteria for location provider:
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);   // fine accuracy
    criteria.setCostAllowed(false);                 // no monetary cost

    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    LatLng myPosition= new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(this, "current position: "+ location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return myPosition; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is useful data for my code i have need only sum small changes and that is solved