# Why I am getting old location coordinates in my Android app while trying to find the current location co-ordinates?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I've simply made an app that shows my current location co-ordinates. But if I change my location then it is shows my old location co-ordinates. Again if I reboot my device it shows the right co-ordinates.
 Here is a part of my code where I got my co-ordinates:

```
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BWN_UPDATE,MIN_DIST_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,this);

                if (locationManager != null){
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                }
                if (location != null){
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                }
```

Comment: Do you keep the GPS on when changing location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **onLocationChanged()** callback instead of **getLastKnownLocation()**. Here is an example code :

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null){
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
            }


        }
    };
```

**How and when to register Location Listener?**

If you want location listener for display current location on map then you should register Location Listener in **onCreate()** or **onResume()** method of the activity and unregister receiver in **onPause()** or **onStop()** method. To unregister location updates you can use the below method.

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener)
```

Also location lock by GPS is always not possible so I will suggest you to use Network provider too. Just add this statement.

```
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BWN_UPDATE,MIN_DIST_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,locationListener);
```

and do this change to your GPS registration statement by putting **locationListener** instead of **this** as your third argument of **locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()**;

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BWN_UPDATE,MIN_DIST_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,locationListener);
```

Comment: I'm still not getting how to implement LocationListener. Can you provide more details. @Best_of_his_name

Comment: Go through [this](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/get-notified-when-location-changes) example.

Comment: [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/location/android-location-based-services-example/) is a little better than the above one. It almost has the complete code with the proper explanation of which part to put where

Comment: don't know why the 2nd link doesn't responded. but i found the solution by using [Fused Location Provider.](http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/).Thank you@Best_of_his_name

Comment: Great!!! And thanks for sharing your link. I hope it helps anyone else who face such issue @ Partha

Answer (score 0):

getLastKnownLocation() isn't good for getting accurate results instantly since it works without waiting for GPS fix - it just gives you location, which is cached by system (you could try running other location using app e.g. Google Maps, then running your and location will be newer).

To make it work as expected you could use onLocationChanged method of LocationListener interface - try one explained here [How to get current location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

The GPS function takes its time to identify your location on request.

While you are changing you location, you need to wait for time that GPS set new location. Till that time, LocationManager will return your old location in :

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

In Samsung Galaxy devices, when you start GPS (Location) button, the icon start blinking in statusbar area. This is to tell user that GPS is searching new location now. When new location is found then the icon will stop blinking and notification will appear **"Location set by GPS"** Technically, you will get callback **onLocationChanged()** at this time. For this callback, you need to implement **LocationListener**

When you are rebooting device, GPS has got sufficient time to set new location so it is giving you correct location