# Google Map Not Showing (Zoom to) Current Location After Set Latitude and Longitude manually

Tags: android, location, google-maps-api-2

I want to show my current location using custom Latitude and Longitude, I have set latitude and longitude in Location object like this :

```
Location location = new Location ("");
location.setLatitude(lat);
location.setLongitude(lon);
```

After that I call onLocationChanged(location) method, where the method is like this :

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng0 = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng0));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

}
```

The map was show, but not showing my current location with blue dot like usual, anybody can help ?

Comment: Are you set callback onlocation update in onCreated method. If not try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17591377/1676666

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to run your code in [GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback)
Likes:

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new OnMapLoadedCallback(){
  @Override
  public void onMapLoaded() {
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng0));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
  }
});
```

**Update:**

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new OnMapLoadedCallback(){
      @Override
      public void onMapLoaded() {
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng0,12));
      }
    });
```

Using

```
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng0,12));
```

Instead of

```
mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng0));
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
```

Because the code `CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12)` is not set Latitude and Longitude, so the values will be inited with [0,0].
That's will let your map center to [0,0]

Comment: still not worked man... do you have another sugestion ?

Comment: Have you put log for lat and lon for location.setLatitude(lat);
location.setLongitude(lon);, what're those values?

Comment: I'm updated my answer, using CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom instead of CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12)