# How to send my current location via SMS?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, sms

How to send my current location via SMS? in Android. Can I get the Source code please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a SMS you can use the SmsManager API : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

And a little search on Google give me this result on how to use the GPS : [How to get current location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android) or you can make a little search in the Android API Manuals.