# onClick method is not working

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-layout, arraylist

I want to use `onClick` method in android button but it is not working correct. On the other hand when I am using `onClickListener` then it is showing me another error like

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

I couldn't find what is the problem with it.

Java code is given below :

```
public void onSearch(View view) throws IOException{

        EditText sLocation = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         String location = sLocation.getText().toString();
         List<android.location.Address> addressList= null;

        if (location != null || !location.equals(""))
        {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            android.location.Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLatitude());
            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("Marker"));
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
        }

    }
```

add_masjid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@string/xyz"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/generalId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rect1"
        android:onClick="onSearch"
        android:text="@string/abc"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/generalId"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:labelFor="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/generalId">

    </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `addressList` is an empty list, you can't get zero index from that, check size of list, if bigger than 0 then continue .

Comment: check condition like that `if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {`.

Comment: .size() method is not resolving in it.

Comment: @NabiaSaroosh Take a `length` instead.

Answer (score 0):

check your `addressList`. It might be empty. That's why you are getting

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: how can I pass value in addressList of location in my case?

Comment: you should not pass value in addressList but it will get populated when It  finds the location from device. so you need to write callback for that. i.e when location is available then perform your tasks.

Comment: how can I write callback in this case?

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17591377/1157879). you will also find lot of examples in google search

Answer (score 0):

the `onClick` method is unrelated to the issue. From the docs for `getFromLocationName`:

> [...]Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is
>   no backend service available.

So chances are good that you may also get an [NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). Do a `null` and an emptiness check to avoid such errors.

Sample solution:

```
public void onSearch(View view) throws IOException {

    EditText sLocation = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String location = sLocation.getText().toString();
    List<android.location.Address> addressList = null;

    if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
            if (addressList != null && !addressList.isEmpty()) {
                android.location.Address address = addressList.get(0);
                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLatitude());
                gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("Marker"));
                gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to resolve address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** this code would block until the `getFromLocationName` method returns. Doing so on the main Thread is a bad idea.

Comment: It is showing me "Failed to resolve address" But I want to resolve it. How can I do this?

Comment: please suggest me how can I do that?

Comment: @NabiaSaroosh I just tested the code by setting the "location" String to my home address in Berlin (without supplying the country). It has correctly resolved the country as "Germany". I guess it can't find anything based on  your input. Try it multiple times with different search queries.

Comment: So, what should I do in my case?

Comment: @NabiaSaroosh the only thing I can suggest at this point - be more precise in what you enter. What text have you provided as "location" String?

Comment: Yes, it is a String in location.

Comment: @NabiaSaroosh what *exactly* have you entered? Try something like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View"

Comment: No, just location name like "Taj mahal or New york" etc.

Comment: Have you any idea?

Comment: well, I haven't worked with `Geocoder` too much, this answer aims at resolving errors in your code. Try different search terms and increasing the maxResutls param, like `geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 5)`