# How to save a tracking in real time with google map

Tags: java, android

The idea is to create an `ArrayList` of locations and every time I save the location data in that list in the same time I draw a polyline between each two points.

My question is about the Google Maps method `onLocationChanged()`. I want to know if it is called automatically, I mean every time the location change, or if it is called when the user click on the button of get current location?

If someone has a better idea please let me know?

Comment: there are many tutorials available for the same. You should have tried at least some of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android)

Comment: i know how to get currentLocation dude this is not duplicated thanks

Answer (score 2):

Basically onLocationChanged is being called everytime the location is changed.
However it's bad idea to implement your code inside it, you can do something like that

```
public class GPSTracker  implements LocationListener{
private Location location ;
public Location getLocation(){
return this.location;
}
// .. code

 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.location=location;
    }

}
```

now in your main activity you can get location by making an object of GPSTracker
then like this

```
GPSTracker=new GPSTracker(this);
gpsTracker.getLocation (); //this will provide you with longitude,latitude then you can control it with a thread or something like that, by calling getLongitude,getLatitude you can get the location paramter
```

be noted the constructor takes context as a parameter so pass the context of your activity to the GPSTracker class
please check the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

As you've not provided your code, I don't know that you have a separate class for getting Location or in the same activity/class.

I am assuming that you want to insert your updated location in an `Arraylist` and want to create a polyline connection all those points. 
if I'm right, Here's what you can do.

- Create an `Arraylist` global variable in your Activity

  ```
  ArrayList<LatLng> cordList = new ArrayList<>();
  ```
- Create a function/method call in `onLocationChanged()`

  ```
  locationMarkers(location);
  //passing updated location to the function/method.
  ```

  (If you have a separate class for getting location then get the reference of your activity in it and call this method using that reference.)
- Then create this method in your activity.

  ```
  public void locationMarkers(Location location){
  cordList.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
  Polyline line =googleMap.addPolyline(newPolylineOptions().width(6).color(Color.GREEN));
  line.setPoints(cordList);
  }
  ```

This way you'll have a polyline on the map of your locations. 
Also this polyline will be a straight line between two markers/positions. 
If you want it to be on the road, use `HashMap`.