# How to get current location and not last location?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the current device location.
All I find is how to get last known location - and for that, I have to first open an app that used location service such as Google Maps. 
But what if I want to be the one to get the current location first, without having to open some other GPS-using app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-on-a)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Look for the answers with FusedLocationProvider for the new API

Answer (score 0):

You need to request location updates. Like `mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(getLocationRequest(), mLocationCallback, null);` And you will get current location inside your `mLocationCallback`. You can look here https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates#updates

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a LocationListener to handle changes in location.
This link might be of some help
   [How to get current location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android)