# Android - How to request location update in the new API?

Tags: java, android

I was playing a bit around the new location API from google (to get latitude and longitude values):

```
private void getLastLocation(){
    FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    try {
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(latitude) + "/" + String.valueOf(longitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot get location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d("LocationFetch", "Error trying to get last GPS location");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
    } catch (SecurityException e){
        Log.d("LocationFetch", "Permission missing");
    }
}
```

When I first tested this code, the `location` was always returning null. However, after opening Instagram (which did a location update on my phone - the geo icon appeared briefly), the `location` was returning my relevant longitude and latitude values.

How do I request a location update on my app using the new API to prevent `location` from being null or retrieve very old locations? (`getLastLocation()` is not enough, possibly `LocationRequest`?)

It is worth noting that I do not want interval updates, I want for it to happen within an Android Service when invoked once.

Comment: use GPSTracker its very essay

Comment: Check this url may be it will help's you
https://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300064/how-to-get-current-location-and-not-last-location/53300121#53300121 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276698/android-my-app-can-get-location-information-until-opening-google-maps-although/53276863#53276863

Comment: Basically you need to create your own location request. Because getLastLocation tries to get location from other apps, and if it exist you will get null.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly add this implementation in your `build.gradle` file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.2.0'//include the latest version of play services
```

After that implement, (implements `LocationListener`) in your activity or fragment and after that implement its function and then

call this method in your `onCreate()` `getLocation();`
and then in this function add these lines

```
protected void getLocation() {
    if (isLocationEnabled(MainActivity.this)) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager)  this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        criteria = new Criteria();
        bestProvider = String.valueOf(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true)).toString();

        //You can still do this if you like, you might get lucky:
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            Log.e("TAG", "GPS is on");
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "latitude:" + latitude + " longitude:" + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            searchNearestPlace(voice2text);
        }
        else{
            //This is what you need:
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 1000, 0, this);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //prompt user to enable location....
        //.................
    }
}
```

After that in your `onLocationChanged(Location location)`
add these lines of code

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //Hey, a non null location! Sweet!

    //remove location callback:
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

    //open the map:
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "latitude:" + latitude + " longitude:" + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    searchNearestPlace(voice2text);
}
```

and you are set to go!!!!
Cheers Happy Coding

Answer (score 2):

It's work for me. Based on [Official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates), every 10 seconds updates the Toast and shows your location:

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private LocationCallback locationCallback;



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startLocationUpdates();

}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    Activity#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
    }
    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
            locationCallback,
            Looper.getMainLooper());
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
}
```

add bellow codes to onCreate method:

```
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(2*5000);

    locationCallback=new LocationCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            if (locationResult == null) {
                return;
            }
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
               // if (location != null) {


                    String Lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                    String Lon = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Lat + " - " + Lon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //    }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

In gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

In code

```
 private void turnGPSOn() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder settingsBuilder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    settingsBuilder.setAlwaysShow(true);

    Task<LocationSettingsResponse> result = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this)
            .checkLocationSettings(settingsBuilder.build());

    result.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
            try {
                LocationSettingsResponse response =
                        task.getResult(ApiException.class);

                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    lat = String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude());
                    lon = String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude());
                }

            } catch (ApiException ex) {
                switch (ex.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        try {
                            ResolvableApiException resolvableApiException =
                                    (ResolvableApiException) ex;
                            resolvableApiException
                                    .startResolutionForResult(SignupActivity.this,
                                            REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:

                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```