# Android gives cached localization when app on background

Tags: android, localization, gps

Android gives old localization (GPS) on my app with actual date after some time  of being in background. 
After changing location (22 kilometers) app gave an old location for around 20 hours with actual timestamp. After 20 hours found a GPS fix and started to send actual position.

```
API: FusedLocationProviderClient

fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates() for new locations
fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation() to get last known location

Android version: 9
```

Comment: Please provide more information: how are You getting location updates, what APIs are You using and how, on what Android version are You testing.

Comment: @OMIsie11
 
API: FusedLocationProviderClient, 

fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates() for new locations, 
fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation() to get last known location, 

Android version: 9

Comment: Also, on what Android have You tested? Stock? Some manufacturer skin? Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60928000/9309845