# onLocationChanged not called on android Q (android 10)

Tags: android, location, android-10.0

I have below codes to request new location:

```
 mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
```

and get call back in public void onLocationChanged(Location location) .

This works fine on android P or below, but I found the callback method onLocationChanged not called on android Q, although I already have the right permissions.

Comment: I'd have a look at [what's new in Android Q regarding privacy and location](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/device-location), but haven't actually gone through that documentation myself yet, so I don't have any specific ideas. Unless if you are trying to receive location in the background.

Comment: please read this https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/device-location

1.<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

Comment: @RajuTukadiya why should I need this?  I just want to get latest location in foreground, not background

Comment: i have one class of locations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android 
please check this . location not getting then contact my email address rajutukadiya3@gmail.com

Comment: @RajuTukadiya no this is not the answer. My codes runs well for years. I just want to know why the callback is not called on android Q

Comment: @tainy did you get the solution??