# How to use Android Location Helper Class in an Activity

Tags: android

I want to access the device's current location in multiple activities. Currently   I'm using Google FusedLocationProvider in one Activity. I'm looking on how to use util/helper class which fetches device's current location to use in different activities. 
I found one helper classes, but not sure how to use it from an Activity. Please help me in the right direction.

**Locator.java**

```
public class Locator implements LocationListener {

static private final String LOG_TAG = "locator";

static private final int TIME_INTERVAL = 100; // minimum time between updates in milliseconds
static private final int DISTANCE_INTERVAL = 1; // minimum distance between updates in meters

static public enum Method {
    NETWORK,
    GPS,
    NETWORK_THEN_GPS
}

private Context context;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private Locator.Method method;
private Locator.Listener callback;

public Locator(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

public void getLocation(Locator.Method method, Locator.Listener callback) {
    this.method = method;
    this.callback = callback;
    switch (this.method) {
        case NETWORK:
        case NETWORK_THEN_GPS:
            Location networkLocation = this.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (networkLocation != null) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Last known location found for network provider : " + networkLocation.toString());
                this.callback.onLocationFound(networkLocation);
            } else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Request updates from network provider.");
                this.requestUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }
            break;
        case GPS:
            Location gpsLocation = this.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (gpsLocation != null) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Last known location found for GPS provider : " + gpsLocation.toString());
                this.callback.onLocationFound(gpsLocation);
            } else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Request updates from GPS provider.");
                this.requestUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void requestUpdates(String provider) {
    if (this.locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
        if (provider.contentEquals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
                && Connectivity.isConnected(this.context)) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Network connected, start listening : " + provider);
            this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, TIME_INTERVAL, DISTANCE_INTERVAL, this);
        } else if (provider.contentEquals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
                && Connectivity.isConnectedMobile(this.context)) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Mobile network connected, start listening : " + provider);
            this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, TIME_INTERVAL, DISTANCE_INTERVAL, this);
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Proper network not connected for provider : " + provider);
            this.onProviderDisabled(provider);
        }
    } else {
        this.onProviderDisabled(provider);
    }
}

public void cancel() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Locating canceled.");
    this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Location found : " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude() + (location.hasAccuracy() ? " : +- " + location.getAccuracy() + " meters" : ""));
    this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    this.callback.onLocationFound(location);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Provider disabled : " + provider);
    if (this.method == Locator.Method.NETWORK_THEN_GPS
            && provider.contentEquals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        // Network provider disabled, try GPS
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Requesst updates from GPS provider, network provider disabled.");
        this.requestUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } else {
        this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        this.callback.onLocationNotFound();
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Provider enabled : " + provider);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Provided status changed : " + provider + " : status : " + status);
}

public interface Listener {
    void onLocationFound(Location location);

    void onLocationNotFound();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android)

Also, take care fetching the location shouldn't be handled in your activity, try to make your view as dump as possible