# How get location?

Tags: android, location, android-permissions

I am developing my first Android app which should get the latitude and longitude of an android device and send it via a web service to a template document.

This is the code from my .java class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class GetLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    EditText textLat;
    EditText textLong;
    EditText lat;
    EditText lon;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.get_location);

        textLat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        textLong = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.longitude);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    private boolean isGPSEnabled() {
        LocationManager cm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return cm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            lat.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            lon.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v){
        if(v.getId() == R.id.getGpsLocation){
            if(!isGPSEnabled()){
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setMessage("Please activate your GPS Location!")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                        .show();
            } else {
                textLat.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
                textLong.setText(String.valueOf(lon));
            }

        }
    }


}
```

I don't get any errors but when I am tapping the button which should get the coordinates, I get 'null' text in both views.

I also have included permissions for internet, access fine and coarse location.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you given location permissions? look at here which already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android

Comment: post your logcat for more information about the bug

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android it may help

Comment: check out this example https://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: [Here is the robust way to get the user's location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50498459/5508673)

Comment: [Here is the robust way to get the user's location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50498459/5508673)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should use GooglePlayServices

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'
```

To get location

```
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
}
if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

After connection

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }
}
```