# How to get current latitude and longitude and show in a toast?

Tags: android

Hello I  know this question is already existed but not getting my solution till now . I have tried many methods to get current location in android studio using java but all are showing the same message **location** is **null** and latitude longitude are showing **0.0/0.0**

Kindly if any body knows the perfect solution to fix this problem ?

Comment: can you post the solution you are following?

Comment: Are u trying in emulator or real device?

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android

Comment: i am testing in real devie