# How to get a user's location in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocation

I have been trying to get user location in a weather app I am building. Since I'm pretty new to android development this is quite tough and so I have tried finding sources on how to make this, though after trying many different things it always ends up being a way too outdated version that no longer works.

So my question is what is currently the best way the get a user's location.

Thanks in advance for anyone that can help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to start reading from official doc: https://developer.android.com/training/location 
or from here ready solution https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-current-location-in-android/

Comment: Do you also have a ready solution that's in Java? The Android docs doesn't show enough of the actual code that I need.

Comment: Depends in your google skills.

Comment: Also, it is not so hard to find solution on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android

Comment: Also,in official google docs, there are kotlin/java examples, just read deeply.

Comment: Im afraid that solution is outdated now, and I wish I knew how to google properly here but since I'm new to android development I have no idea what to look for

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current tells you exactly how to get started with copiable java code.

Comment: @codebod nice, thats I was talking about, just need to read, understand and implement, no one will implement it instead of you